# Combine & SwiftUI with a custom Publisher - unexpected behaviour when using .assign subscriber

Tags: swift, realm, swiftui, combine

I've created a custom Publisher for use with a Realm database which seems to function as expected in isolation but doesn't want to play nicely with SwiftUI.

I've isolated the issue to the interface between the view model and SwiftUI. The view model appears to behave as expected based on the results from the various property observers and .print() statements I've dropped in for the bug hunt but outside the scope of the view model, the view model's data repository (represented by the 'state' property) is reported as empty hence the blank UI.

Interestingly, if I replace my Combine code with a straight array conversion of the Realm Results query the UI is displayed as expected (although I haven't implemented notification tokens for a dynamic update when items are added/deleted, etc).

I suspect I can't see the wood for all the trees so an outside perspective and guidance would be very much appreciated :-)

Codebase below - I've left out Apple-generated boilerplate for the most part.

**SceneDelegate:**

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
        // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
        // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).

        // Create the SwiftUI view that provides the window contents.
        let patientService = MockPatientService()
        let viewModel = AnyViewModel(PatientListViewModel(patientService: patientService))
        print("#(function) viewModel contains \(viewModel.state.patients.count) patients")
        let contentView = PatientListView()
            .environmentObject(viewModel)

        // Use a UIHostingController as window root view controller.
        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }
```

**Patient.swift**

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

@objcMembers final class Patient: Object, Identifiable {
    dynamic let id: String = UUID().uuidString
    dynamic var name: String = ""

    required init() {
        super.init()
    }

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

**PatientService**

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

@objcMembers final class Patient: Object, Identifiable {
    dynamic let id: String = UUID().uuidString
    dynamic var name: String = ""

    required init() {
        super.init()
    }

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
import Foundation
import Combine

protocol ViewModel: ObservableObject where ObjectWillChangePublisher.Output == Void {
    associatedtype State // the type of the state of a given scene
    associatedtype Input // inputs to the view model that are transformed by the trigger method

    var state: State { get }
    func trigger(_ input: Input)
}

final class AnyViewModel<State, Input>: ObservableObject { // wrapper enables "effective" (not true) type erasure of the view model
    private let wrappedObjectWillChange: () -> AnyPublisher<Void, Never>
    private let wrappedState: () -> State
    private let wrappedTrigger: (Input) -> Void


    var objectWillChange: some Publisher {
        wrappedObjectWillChange()
    }

    var state: State {
        wrappedState()
    }

    func trigger(_ input: Input) {
        wrappedTrigger(input)
    }

    init<V: ViewModel>(_ viewModel: V) where V.State == State, V.Input == Input {
        self.wrappedObjectWillChange = { viewModel.objectWillChange.eraseToAnyPublisher() }
        self.wrappedState = { viewModel.state }
        self.wrappedTrigger = viewModel.trigger
    }
}

extension AnyViewModel: Identifiable where State: Identifiable {
    var id: State.ID {
        state.id
    }
}
```

**RealmCollectionPublisher**

```
import Foundation
import Combine
import RealmSwift

// MARK: Custom publisher - produces a stream of Object arrays in response to change notifcations on a given Realm collection
extension Publishers {
    struct Realm<Collection: RealmCollection>: Publisher {
        typealias Output = Array<Collection.Element>
        typealias Failure = Never // TODO: Not true but deal with this later

        let collection: Collection

        init(collection: Collection) {
            self.collection = collection
        }

        func receive<S>(subscriber: S) where S : Subscriber, Failure == S.Failure, Output == S.Input {
            let subscription = RealmSubscription(subscriber: subscriber, collection: collection)
            subscriber.receive(subscription: subscription)
        }
    }
}

// MARK: Convenience accessor function to the custom publisher
extension Publishers {
    static func realm<Collection: RealmCollection>(collection: Collection) -> Publishers.Realm<Collection> {
        return Publishers.Realm(collection: collection)
    }
}

// MARK: Custom subscription
private final class RealmSubscription<S: Subscriber, Collection: RealmCollection>: Subscription where S.Input == Array<Collection.Element> {
    private var subscriber: S?
    private let collection: Collection
    private var notificationToken: NotificationToken?

    init(subscriber: S, collection: Collection) {
        self.subscriber = subscriber
        self.collection = collection

        self.notificationToken = collection.observe { (changes: RealmCollectionChange) in
            switch changes {
            case .initial:
                // Results are now populated and can be accessed without blocking the UI
                print("Initial")
                subscriber.receive(Array(collection.elements))
            case .update(_, let deletions, let insertions, let modifications):
                print("Updated")
                subscriber.receive(Array(collection.elements))
            case .error(let error):
                fatalError("\(error)")
                #warning("Impl error handling - do we want to fail or log and recover?")
            }
        }
    }

    func request(_ demand: Subscribers.Demand) {
        // no impl as RealmSubscriber is effectively just a sink
    }

    func cancel() {
        print("Cancel called on RealnSubscription")
        subscriber = nil
        notificationToken = nil
    }

    deinit {
        print("RealmSubscription de-initialised")
    }
}
```

**PatientListViewModel**

```
class PatientListViewModel: ViewModel {
    @Published var state: PatientListState = PatientListState(patients: [AnyViewModel<PatientDetailState, Never>]()) {
        willSet {
            print("Current PatientListState : \(newValue)")
        }
    }

    private let patientService: PatientService
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    init(patientService: PatientService) {
        self.patientService = patientService

        // Scenario 1 - This code sets state which is correctly shown in UI (although not dynamically updated)
        let viewModels = patientService.allPatientsAsArray()
            .map { AnyViewModel(PatientDetailViewModel(patient: $0, patientService: patientService)) }
        self.state = PatientListState(patients: viewModels)

        // Scenario 2 (BUGGED) - This publisher's downstream emissions update dynamically, downstream outputs are correct and the willSet observer suggests .assign is working
        // but the UI does not reflect the changes (if the above declarative code is removed, the number of patients is always zero)
        let publishedState = Publishers.realm(collection: patientService.allPatientsAsResults())
            .print()
            .map { results in
                results.map { AnyViewModel(PatientDetailViewModel(patient: $0, patientService: patientService)) } }
            .map { PatientListState(patients: $0) }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
            .assign(to: \.state, on: self)
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }

    func trigger(_ input: PatientListInput) {
        switch(input) {
        case .delete(let indexSet):
            let patient = state.patients[indexSet.first!].state.patient
            patientService.deletePatient(patient)
            print("Deleting item at index \(indexSet.first!) - patient is \(patient)")
            #warning("Know which patient to remove but need to ensure the state is updated")
        }
    }

    deinit {
        print("Viewmodel being deinitialised")
    }
}
```

**PatientListView**

```
struct PatientListState {
    var patients: [AnyViewModel<PatientDetailState, Never>]
}

enum PatientListInput {
    case delete(IndexSet)
}


struct PatientListView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: AnyViewModel<PatientListState, PatientListInput> 

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {

            VStack {
                Text("Patients: \(viewModel.state.patients.count)")

                List {
                    ForEach(viewModel.state.patients) { viewModel in
                        PatientCell(patient: viewModel.state.patient)
                    }
                    .onDelete(perform: deletePatient)

                }
                .navigationBarTitle("Patients")
            }
        }
    }

    private func deletePatient(at offset: IndexSet) {
        viewModel.trigger(.delete(offset))
    }
}
```

**PatientDetailViewModel**

```
class PatientDetailViewModel: ViewModel {
    @Published private(set) var state: PatientDetailState
    private let patientService: PatientService
    private let patient: Patient

    init(patient: Patient, patientService: PatientService) {
        self.patient = patient
        self.patientService = patientService
        self.state = PatientDetailState(patient: patient)
    }

    func trigger(_ input: Never) {
        // TODO: Implementation
    }
}
```

**PatientDetailView**

```
struct PatientDetailState {
    let patient: Patient
    var name: String {
        patient.name
    }
}

extension PatientDetailState: Identifiable {
    var id: Patient.ID {
        patient.id
    }
}

struct PatientDetailView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/"Hello, World!"/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
    }
}

struct PatientDetailView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        PatientDetailView()
    }
}
```

[image: **Using arrays:**]
[image: **Using custom Publisher**]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if one/both of these is/are the actual problem, but are good places to look:
(1) a race condition in which the async code isn't performing the `assign(to:on:)` before the `PatientListView` appears.
(2) you are receiving the results on a background thread.

For the latter, be sure to use `receive(on: RunLoop.main)` before your `assign(to:on:)`, since `state` is being used by the UI. You can replace the `.eraseToAnyPublisher()` with the `receive(on:)`, since you don't really need the type erasure in the current scenario (it's not breaking anything, but it's not needed).

```swift
       let publishedState = Publishers.realm(collection: patientService.allPatientsAsResults())
            .print()
            .map { results in
                results.map { AnyViewModel(PatientDetailViewModel(patient: $0, patientService: patientService)) } }
            .map { PatientListState(patients: $0) }
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .assign(to: \.state, on: self)
            .store(in: &cancellables)
```

Comment: After kicking myself for forgetting about asynchronous operations (can you tell I'm still finding my feet with reactive programming?) I added 'receive(on:)' and also ensured that the query of the Realm DB only tool place after the view appeared (by adding another Input case and then flat mapping this with stream from the Realm publisher. I thought that would do it but sadly I'm no further forward and the code base is a total mess so I'm going to junk it and start again. Watch this space...